# Issue with iOS simulator using MAUI with Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ios-simulator, maui

I use VS2022 17.8.3 with Windows10.
I have a Mac Mini connected with XCode 15.1 and MacOS 13.6.1

When I want to debug my .NET MAUI app the iOS simulator does not launch. I do not receive any error message, the simulator just do not start.

The iOS simulator is launched correctly when I run a demo .NET MAUI app on my windows machine.

I checked the existing questions regarding this topic but the answers did not help me.

Thank you for any help!

What I have tried:
Update all related software.
Run the simulator on the mac using xcode.
Restart VS2022
Reboot windows and MacOS

Comment: ```The iOS simulator is launched correctly when I run a demo .NET MAUI app on my windows machine.```   The default maui template works but your project does not work?

Comment: Then do you add any third party nuget or use [ios capabilities](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/capabilities?view=net-maui-8.0&tabs=vs)?

Comment: You may also try [Clearing the Broker, IDB, Build, and Designer Agents on the Mac](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/troubleshooting#clearing-the-broker-idb-build-and-designer-agents-on-the-mac). For more info, please refer to [Connection Troubleshooting for a Xamarin.iOS Build Host](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/troubleshooting)

Comment: I did not add iOS capabilities. I fixed the issue by checking the csproj file and removing a section which contained inconsistent information about provisioning.
Thank you for your feedback!

Comment: Good job! Feel free to post an answer below, which could help others with similar questions!